# How do you convert a string into an Observable<Bool>?

Tags: string, mvvm, observable, rx-swift

How do you convert a string into an observable ? I have json that is returning as a string and I need to convert it into a Observable type and I make not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're looking for, but you can try this:

```
let stringObservable = Observable.just("your string here") 
let boolObservableA = stringObservable.map(yourStringToBooleanMapper)
let boolObservableB = stringObservable.map{yourStringToBooleanMapper($0)}
```

Comment: Is yourStringToBooleanMapper some sort of function and what if I was trying to convert it from an observable<String> to Observable<Bool>?

Comment: yes, it must be a function, map expects a function that converts the Element published in the stream to another type, Like this:
func yourStringToBooleanMapper(_ s: String) -> Bool {...} 

or

let yourStringToBooleanMapper : (String) -> Bool = {s in ...}

For example: Observable.just("your string here").map{$0.isEmpty} will return an Observable<Bool>

Use playgrounds to try it out and download the Rx project which comes with lots of examples.